# Python - Error related to path

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using the code from here:

http://pythoncentral.io/finding-duplicate-files-with-python/

to find duplicated files in a folder.

Those are my first steps in Python (I come form VBA for Excel) and my problem is probably very simple, but I tried several things without success. After running the code I get the message:

```
-f is not a valid path, please verify
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

%tb generates:

```
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-31268a802b4a> in <module>()
     11             else:
     12                 print('%s is not a valid path, please verify' % i)
---> 13                 sys.exit()
     14         printResults(dups)
     15     else:

SystemExit:
```

The code I am using is:

```
# dupFinder.py
import os, sys
import hashlib

def findDup(parentFolder):
    # Dups in format {hash:[names]}
    dups = {}
    for dirName, subdirs, fileList in os.walk(parentFolder):
        print('Scanning %s...' % dirName)
        for filename in fileList:
            # Get the path to the file
            path = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
            # Calculate hash
            file_hash = hashfile(path)
            # Add or append the file path
            if file_hash in dups:
                dups[file_hash].append(path)
            else:
                dups[file_hash] = [path]
    return dups


# Joins two dictionaries
def joinDicts(dict1, dict2):
    for key in dict2.keys():
        if key in dict1:
            dict1[key] = dict1[key] + dict2[key]
        else:
            dict1[key] = dict2[key]


def hashfile(path, blocksize = 65536):
    afile = open(path, 'rb')
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    buf = afile.read(blocksize)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        hasher.update(buf)
        buf = afile.read(blocksize)
    afile.close()
    return hasher.hexdigest()


def printResults(dict1):
    results = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, dict1.values()))
    if len(results) > 0:
        print('Duplicates Found:')
        print('The following files are identical. The name could differ, but the content is identical')
        print('___________________')
        for result in results:
            for subresult in result:
                print('\t\t%s' % subresult)
            print('___________________')

    else:
        print('No duplicate files found.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
path='C:/DupTestFolder/' #this is the path to analyze for duplicated files
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        dups = {}
        folders = sys.argv[1:]
        for i in folders:
            # Iterate the folders given
            if os.path.exists(i):
                # Find the duplicated files and append them to the dups
                joinDicts(dups, findDup(i))
            else:
                print('%s is not a valid path, please verify' % i)
                sys.exit()
        printResults(dups)
    else:
        print('Usage: python dupFinder.py folder or python dupFinder.py folder1 folder2 folder3')
```

I tried ending the path with and without "\" at the end, but the result is the same.

I am running Jupyter with Python 3.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The *path* variable is not used in your code.

All you do is an iteration over `sys.argv[1:]`, which are the parameters of your script. You consider each parameter as a directory path.

On a Windows console, You can try:

```
python dupFinder.py C:\DupTestFolder
```

It should work.

Comment: I am running in Jupyter, but I see that the solution: 
    
 python dupFinder.py C:\DupTestFolder 
 
doesn't work there. I tried the same with the following result:

    Invalid Syntax
 
I am using the path to reach dupFinder.py, but that didn't help either.

    python C:\AnacondaProjects\dupFinder.py C:\DupTestFolder
 
alse returns Invalid Syntax

I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Thanks!, I am able to run the code now. I have to do two things:

1. Save the dupFinder.py to the same folder that runs my python installation, in my case C:\Users\Pepe

Answer (score 0):

Sys.argv works in command line window and takes arguments. It doesn't work with jupyter notebook naturally, or you need to figure out some commands in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!, I am able to run the code now. I have to do two things:

1. Save the dupFinder.py to the same folder that runs my python installation, in my case C:\Users\Pepe
2. Open the cmd window from Anaconda (that creates the cmd window in the folder where python is running), I presume I could do the same open the command window and navigate (cd\ command) to the folder location
3. Finally run python dupFinder.py C:\DupTestFolder.

Now I need to find out how to have the results saved to a .txt file for future use, I will search for it before posting. Thanks for your help!